# c# tesseract2 ocr recognizes 2 instead of 3

Tags: c#, tesseract

[image: img1]
<sub>(source: [askdev.ru](http://u.askdev.ru/501/d0d4/d852f8/large.gif))</sub>

[image: img2]
<sub>(source: [askdev.ru](http://u.askdev.ru/501/d0d5/b0d8fd/large.gif))</sub>

As a result, I have 298 and 288.

```
tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "$,0123456789");
ocr.Init("C:\\tessdata\\", "eng", false); 

Bitmap tmp = wbbmp.Clone(rectM[5], System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

List<tessnet2.Word> n = ocr.DoOCR(tmp, new Rectangle(0,0,75,21));
```

Comment: What happens if you invert the images first?

Comment: Hello, try to hide $ I think it will work

Comment: @HassanBoutougha: How will this help the OP? Isn't the OCR supposed to recognize the dollar sign?